# Where to keep extra parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have few big databases with lot of records (look like city-city-price).
Also I have dozen modifying parameters for price.
Where should I keep this parameters?
I see 3 options:

- Create DB with fields for each parameter (but this'll be DB with only one record and scalabiliy isn't good)
- Create DB with one field and make record for every parameter (but I should remember the meaning of every record)
- Hardcode parameters in controller

All options don't seem to be elegant. Is there any other good solution for such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is a nice way of handling some values throughout the application without any association of Model.

Otherwise, just create a file like `config/initializers/constants_file.rb` and place the values in that file, so that those can be accessed by any where after restarting the server.

for example, in `config/initializers/constants_file.rb` i have the following

```
CURRENCY_TYPES = {:city1 => "value1", :city2 => "value2", ...}
```

and you can access this any where from app like **CURRENCY_TYPES[:city1]**.

Or still you can create a Constant in model and you can use that if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to store somewhere fixed parameters like city names or price currency. These being rather a list of items than dynamic variables.

The standard ways to handle it would be to use a configuration file like a yaml. This enable you to map keys to values of your parameters.

I advise you to look at the [YAML Configuration File](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file?view=comments) railscast if it suits:

Otherwise you can also create a new model to keep all the values in the DB. This choice may be better if you want to dynamically change the list in production for instance.